# Looping HTML table with JavaScript and PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I'm delevoling an app with phonegap for android and I'm trying to make a `FOR` loop in javascript with html table rows. I tried using the `document.write` but all of the content in the page desapears, show just what it's in the `document.write`.
The code I have is this one:

```
<table id="hor-minimalist-b">
<script language=javascript>
for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
    document.write('<tr>');
        document.write('<td>');
        document.write('<input type="text" name="valor" id="valor" value="key' + i'">');
        document.write('</td>');
        document.write('</tr>');
}
</script>
</table>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are just putting text in the page, you need to "create" the element and append them to the table.
You can do it this way:

```
<table id="hor-minimalist-b"><thead></thead><tbody></tbody></table>
<script language="javascript">
var table = document.getElementById('hor-minimalist-b'); // get the table element
var tableBody = table.childNodes[1]; // get the table body
var tableHead = table.childNodes[0]; // get the table head
for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
    var row = document.createElement('tr'); // create a new row
    var cell = document.createElement('td'); // create a new cell
    var input = document.createElement('input'); // create a new input
    // Set input properties
    input.type = "text";
    input.id = "valor"; // It's not a good idea (to have elements with the same id..)
    input.name = "valor";
    input.value = "key" + i;
    cell.appendChild(input); // append input to the new cell
    row.appendChild(cell); // append the new cell to the new row
    tableBody.appendChild(row); // append the row to table body
}
</script>
```

insertRow() and insertCell() will probably work too, but I did not test it yet

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I kinda new on javascript. I'm not sure if I understand: To the code that I have I should add this one you gave me?
Another thing, can you explain me wht is the purpose of the tableBody = table.firstChild; please? Thanks

Comment: You should replace your code with this one.
Using tbody is a good practice, it will make your code compatible with Internet Explorer.

Comment: It works, thanks a lot:) by the way, I want to add a theader. can you edit that code you made with that? I trying to understand it still. thanks :)

Comment: Sure, it's edited and with comments to help you understand it.

Comment: Thank you so much. That really helped. I'm sorry I keep asking new things but, if I had the <th> tag I have to create the var with the document.createElement too, isn't it? And, if I want to put plain text between the <td></td> how can I do it? Thanks again